# A good reference on cosmic ray?

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, cosmic-rays

I am looking for a good reference on cosmic ray, both galactic and solar. Does anyone have any suggestion?

I'm looking for a reference that covers the production and propagation of cosmic rays in a rigorous way. It should target people that know about particle physics, but are ignorant about cosmic rays.

Comment: [The Nine Lives of Cosmic Rays in Galaxies; Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-astro-082214-122457?journalCode=astro)

Comment: Also try:
[ The Net Advance of Physics: COSMIC RAYS](http://web.mit.edu/redingtn/www/netadv/Xcosmicray.html)

Comment: @MSulkanen Perhaps you could convert those to answers, with relevant details.

Comment: Please [do not make your post look like a revision table](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/25301), instead just seamlessly integrate the new material into the post. There is an edit history button at the bottom of the post for those interested in seeing what changed.

Comment: I hope those that opted to downvote the question from it's original format will choose to at least un-vote (if not upvote) now that's been improved with the extra details. This is a useful question for those of us that study/studied cosmic rays.

Comment: @Chair FWIW, both of those links by MSulkanen *were* posted as answers, but were converted to comments by a mod due to them being relevant link-only answers.

Comment: @KyleKanos Still, it'd be better if MSulkanen could turn them into answers by adding the relevant details, as I mentioned in my previous comment. Like this, it's not possible to downvote those recommendations, and replying to them is messy. Also, with the edited state question, I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinhard Schlickeiser's [*Cosmic Ray Astrophysics*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540664659) (Springer publisher link) is probably a good starting point for you. From the "about this textbook" in the link:

> This book provides an exhaustive account of the origin and dynamics of cosmic rays.

It may be a little dated, having been printed in 2002 ([pre-*Fermi LAT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_Gamma-ray_Space_Telescope)), but it covers exactly what you want: the production & propagation of cosmic rays--it's been a while since I read it (having moved away from academia a few years ago), but I believe it covers galactic CRs (which ought to cover solar as well) and I think it does touch upon extra-galactic CRs.

I don't really recall it being particularly difficult with the maths beyond e.g. vector calculus. A background in astrophysics is probably useful, especially with radiative processes (i.e., having read/worked through [Rybicki & Lightman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471827592)). I don't think particle physics knowledge is needed in the book, but, again, it's been a while since I've needed to look at it.

Comment: Additionally: I have heard about Gaisser's [*Cosmic Rays and Particle Physics*](https://www.amazon.com/Cosmic-Particle-Physics-Thomas-Gaisser/dp/0521339316) and Shalchi's [*Nonlinear Cosmic Ray Diffusion Theores*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642003080), but have not read either.

Answer (score 1):

A good an updated (2016) reference is [Cosmic rays and particle physics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cosmic-rays-and-particle-physics/C81BA71195ADFC89EFCC2C565B617702), by T. Gaisser, R. Engel and E. Resconi, active researchers in the field. It includes a lot of the recent results in UHECR (Ultra high energy cosmic rays, energies of around $10^{20}\,\mathrm{eV}$) by currently running experiments (like Telescope Array, the Auger Observatory, or the Icecube observatory). It goes through some particle physics, and talks about acceleration and propagation of cosmic rays in the galaxy and outside, although it may not go too far in solar cosmic rays. I would say that the book is rigorous enough, but one can't forget that our knowledge about cosmic ray production is limited. What I like about the book is that it provides a good description about the many parts of physics that come together in cosmic ray physics.